# replace GlobalScope.launch in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am writing some pager code in jetpack compose and came to a situation where I need to change page number by button click. This is my event on button click:

```
onClick = {pagerState.scrollToPage(page=currentPager+1)}
```

but when I do this I get this error: `Suspend function 'scrollToPage' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`

I got a solution to this by adding:

```
onClick = {GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main) {pagerState.scrollToPage(page=currentPager+1)}}
```

but still GlobalScope.launch is not recommended. Above onClick are called inside basic compose functions. How can I fix this issue in jetpack compose?

Comment: Which Compose Widget you are using for pager??

Comment: I am using accompanist pager. -> com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.20.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go through this documentation : [Accompanist Pager](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/)

Here is a raw code: [Raw code for scroll to page](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/PhongHuynh93/ae551f8c9f82041782265ff80b87fe20/raw/84b174eb33057adea41a73de5e60538bf9fe1883/CombinedTab.kt)

If you want to jump to a specific page, you either call call pagerState.scrollToPage(index) or pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index) method in a CoroutineScope:

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

HorizontalPager(count = 10, state = pagerState) { page ->
    // ...page content
}

// Later, scroll to page 2
scope.launch {
    pagerState.scrollToPage(2)
}
```

Comment: I have found a solution from this answer and help of above answer. I have made an edit to show how scope is defined in the first place. This worked.

Comment: That's great Brother

Answer (score 7):

You should use the code below to create a coroutines scope in your composable.

```
val coroutinesScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
```

Note that you can only call this inside a composable so you cannot create `coroutinesScope` inside your `onClick()` and have to initialize it on the top of your composable.

Comment: This perfectly defines how a coroutine scope is defined and upvoted, but the complete solution is shown in the above answer, thus tick marked it. Thanks